# Tor on Android, is it even secure?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, orbot, android

While I made some good experiences using Tor on Tails, I was wondering if using Tor on Android makes any sense at all, as I have been strongly advised against using it.

After spending some hours reading myself into it, I still can't fully understand the matter and hope someone can clarify here?

I read that routing App-Traffic through Orbot is not a bulletproof option, as leaks are still possible. Does it make sense to use a No-Root Firewall to stop Apps like Google from communicating with the Internet or does a so called No-Root Firewall pose a risk itself?

After all the main question remains: Should you use TOR on Android if you are in a country where you can face serious consequences for doing certain things that are not illegal in other countries? After my researches, I have a strong feeling Tor on Android isn't a secure thing to use. Can someone confirm or take my worries away?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can access Tor through the official [Tor Browser app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.torproject.torbrowser&hl=en_US&gl=US) on Android, which is your safest option.

Comment: That was what I thought.  The question still remains if Tor on Android is safe after all.

Comment: Nothing is 100% safe. Tor Browser on Android should be as safe as Tor Browser on a computer.

Comment: Are you sure about that? If you have some Fürther knowledge, could you please share if using the Orbot routing traffic over internal VPN or a No-Root Firewall is the preferred way of blocking Apps from communicating with the Internet?

Comment: I don't think there is a preferred way, especially if you can "face serious consequences" for what you do over Tor. Using Orbot or custom firewall rules is more risky than using only the Tor Browser as there are more ways to leak personal information. It's up to you to decide whether this level of risk is acceptable.